# Database backup via SMO (SQL Server Management Objects) in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, smo

I need to backup database (using SQL Server 2008 R2). Size of db is about 100 GB so I want backup content only of important tables (containing settings) and of course object of all tables, views, triggers etc.

For example:

- db: `Products`
- tables: `Food, Clothes, Cars`

There is too much cars in `Cars`, so I will only backup table definition (`CREATE TABLE ...`) and complete `Food` and `Clothes` (including its content).

Advise me the best solution, please. I will probably use SMO (if no better solution). Should I use `Backup` class? Or `Scripter` class? Or another (if there is any)? Which class can handle my requirements?

I want backup these files to `*.sql` files, one per table if possible.

I would appreciate code sample. Written in answer or somewhere (post url), but be sure that external article has solution exactly for this kind of problem.

You can use this part of code

```
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection("SERVER,1234", "User", "User1234");
Server server = new Server(connection);
Database database = server.Databases["DbToBackup"];
```

Comment: Why can't you do the backup through SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Because it's not my server. I only code application for client. He is IT newbie, he can't do it by himself.

Comment: Regular SQL Server backup only works on a **database** or **file group** level - you cannot selectively back up certain tables and omit others. If you want to script out to SQL, then you need to use SMO and the `Scripter` class - not sure if that supports scripting out the **contents** of the tables, too - you'd have to try.

Comment: True, but you can selectively export your data as such to a reusable format. 'Backup' is contextual.

Comment: Thx to marc_s for edit of my post. This looks better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/archive/2010/03/03/generating-sql-backup-script-for-tables-amp-data-from-any-net-application-using-smo.aspx) arcitle was enough informative to solve my problem. Here is my working solution.
I decided script all objects to one file, it's better solution because of dependencies, I think. If there is one table per on file and there is also some dependencies (foreign keys for example) it would script more code than if everything is in one file.

I omitted some parts of code in this sample, like backuping backup files in case wrong database backup. If there is no such a system, all backups will script to one file and it will go messy

```
public class DatabaseBackup
{
    private ServerConnection Connection;
    private Server Server;
    private Database Database;
    private ScriptingOptions Options;
    private string FileName;
    private const string NoDataScript = "Cars";

    public DatabaseBackup(string server, string login, string password, string database)
    {
        Connection = new ServerConnection(server, login, password);
        Server = new Server(Connection);
        Database = Server.Databases[database];
    }

    public void Backup(string fileName)
    {
        FileName = fileName;
        SetupOptions();

        foreach (Table table in Database.Tables)
        {
             if (!table.IsSystemObject)
             {
                  if (NoDataScript.Contains(table.Name))
                  {
                       Options.ScriptData = false;
                       table.EnumScript(Options);
                       Options.ScriptData = true;
                  }
                  else
                       table.EnumScript(Options);
              }
         }
    }

    private void SetupOptions()
    {
         Options = new ScriptingOptions();
         Options.ScriptSchema = true;
         Options.ScriptData = true;
         Options.ScriptDrops = false;
         Options.WithDependencies = true;
         Options.Indexes = true;
         Options.FileName = FileName;
         Options.EnforceScriptingOptions = true;
         Options.IncludeHeaders = true;
         Options.AppendToFile = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using SMO. You will have to play with the options you need.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString")) {
    ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(connection);
    Server server = new Server(serverConnection);
    Database database = server.Databases["databaseName"];
    Scripter scripter = new Scripter(server);
    scripter.Options.ScriptDrops = false;
    scripter.Options.WithDependencies = true;
    scripter.Options.ScriptData = true;
    Urn[] smoObjects = new Urn[1];
    foreach (Table table in database.Tables) {
        smoObjects[0] = table.Urn;
        if (!table.IsSystemObject) {
            foreach (string s in scripter.EnumScript(smoObjects)) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
                sb.AppendLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
// Write to *.sql file on disk
File.WriteAllText(@".\backup.sql");
```

Another easy way to do this is by backing the database to xml files. To do this use a DataTable and call WriteXml and WriteXmlSchema. (You need the schema later on so it can be imported/restored using the same method). This method means you are backing up per table.

```
private bool BackupTable(string connectionString, string tableName, string directory) {
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
        try {
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex) {
            // Handle
            return false;
        }
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", tableName), connection)) {
            using (DataTable table = new DataTable(tableName)) {
                adapter.Fill(table);
                try {
                    table.WriteXml(Path.Combine(directory, string.Format("{0}.xml", tableName)));
                    table.WriteXmlSchema(Path.Combine(directory, string.Format("{0}.xsd", tableName)));
                }
                catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException ex) {
                    // Handle
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can later on then push these back into a database us by using ReadXmlSchema and ReadXml, using an adapter to fill and update the table to the database. I assume you are knowledgable in basic CRUD so I shouldn't need to cover that part.

If you want to use SMO, here is a Msdn article on using the Backup and Restore classes to backup and restore a database. The code sample us unformatted, and in VB.NET, but easily translatable.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162133(v=SQL.100).aspx

Lastly, which may be easier, talk to the IT guys and see if they will let you remote in or give you access to do the backup yourself. If you are writing the software and this is a crucial step, speak up and let them know how important it is for you to do this, as this will reduce cost in you having to write a custom tool when great tools already exist. Especially since the database is 100GB, you can use the tools you know already work.

Comment: Read properly my question, please. *I want backup these files to *.sql files.*

Comment: I understand that clearly, but this is not an easy task you can find resources for readily without hours of research. There are better solutions out there, such as using the SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard which does exactly what you want and if it is viable for your situation. You can even try http://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/archive/2010/03/03/generating-sql-backup-script-for-tables-amp-data-from-any-net-application-using-smo.aspx, but it looks sketchy as well. This may help as well: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SMO/scriptdatabaseobjectswithsmo/2342/

Comment: I finished it an hour ago thanks to url you posted in your comment. I found it too. But I am not allowed to anwser my own question yet, so I will post working solution tomorrow.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working solution for you, as well.

Comment: Oh I see familiar commands. I appreciate your interest, may your solution helps others. I am still going to post my solution as best solution, because it suits best for my problem. If you understand that code you post, you will see more suitable variant tomorrow, no need of Urn objects, no need of scripter object. But thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Server databaseServer = default(Server);//DataBase Server Name
databaseServer = new Server("ecrisqlstddev");

string strFileName = @"C:\Images\UltimateSurveyMod_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".sql"; //20120720

if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName))
    System.IO.File.Delete(strFileName);

List<SqlSmoObject> list = new List<SqlSmoObject>();
Scripter scripter = new Scripter(databaseServer);

Database dbUltimateSurvey = databaseServer.Databases["UltimateSurvey"];//DataBase Name

// Table scripting Writing
DataTable dataTable1 = dbUltimateSurvey.EnumObjects(DatabaseObjectTypes.Table);

foreach (DataRow drTable in dataTable1.Rows)
{
    // string strTableSchema = (string)drTable["Schema"];
    // if (strTableSchema == "dbo")
    //    continue;
    Table dbTable = (Table)databaseServer.GetSmoObject(new Urn((string)drTable["Urn"]));

    if (!dbTable.IsSystemObject)
        if (dbTable.Name.Contains("SASTool_"))
            list.Add(dbTable);
}

scripter.Server = databaseServer;

scripter.Options.IncludeHeaders = true;
scripter.Options.SchemaQualify = true;
scripter.Options.ToFileOnly = true;
scripter.Options.FileName = strFileName;
scripter.Options.DriAll = true;
scripter.Options.AppendToFile = true;

scripter.Script(list.ToArray());     // Table Script completed

// Stored procedures scripting writing
list = new List<SqlSmoObject>();

DataTable dataTable = dbUltimateSurvey.EnumObjects(DatabaseObjectTypes.StoredProcedure);

foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    string sSchema = (string)row["Schema"];

    if (sSchema == "sys" || sSchema == "INFORMATION_SCHEMA")
        continue;

    StoredProcedure sp = (StoredProcedure)databaseServer.GetSmoObject(
               new Urn((string)row["Urn"]));

    if (!sp.IsSystemObject)
        if (sp.Name.Contains("custom_"))
            list.Add(sp);
}

scripter.Server = databaseServer;

scripter.Options.IncludeHeaders = true;
scripter.Options.SchemaQualify = true;
scripter.Options.ToFileOnly = true;
scripter.Options.FileName = strFileName;
scripter.Options.DriAll = true;
scripter.Options.AppendToFile = true;

scripter.Script(list.ToArray());    // Stored procedures script completed
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not really a Backup but I understand what your goal is:

- [Scripter sample code](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scripting-database-objects-using-smo-updated)
- [Using SMO to get create script for table defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274408/using-smo-to-get-create-script-for-table-defaults/274578#274578)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwories/archive/2005/05/07/basic-scripting.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/archive/2010/03/03/generating-sql-backup-script-for-tables-amp-data-from-any-net-application-using-smo.aspx
- http://en.csharp-online.net/SQL_Server_Management_Objects
- http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1833/generate-scripts-for-database-objects-with-smo-for-sql-server/

For "Backup" of Data you could load the table content via a `Reader` into a `DataTable` and store the result as XML...